# DB2 SQL columns to rows

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, crosstab

I am trying to convert columns into rows like the example below.

```
 _________________________________     ROW       | Columns  | values_
      |Column1 | Column2  | Column3   _____________________________
 _________________________________     1         | 1        | 12 
 Row 1|     12  |     25  |     11     1         | 2        | 25
 Row 2|     30  |      5  |     15 --> 1         | 3        | 11
                                       2         | 1        | 30
                                       2         | 2        | 5
                                       2         | 3        | 15
```

For solving this i used following Statement

```
with t as (
      <my query which builds the cross tab>
     )
select t.Row,
       (case when n.n = 1 then Column1
             when n.n = 2 then Column2
             when n.n = 3 then Column3
        end) as values_
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 2 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all
      select 3 from sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) n;
```

but I got the following Error

> THE STATEMENT CANNOT BE EXECUTED BY DB2 OR IN THE ACCELERATOR (REASON
>   7). SQLCODE=-4742, SQLSTATE=560D5, DRIVER=4.19.56

Has someone any hints to solve this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

This represents your base table..

```
db2 => WITH BASE(RID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) AS  
        (VALUES ('Row 1', 12, 25, 11), 
                ('Row 2', 30, 5, 15)) 
       SELECT * FROM BASE
    
    RID   COLUMN1     COLUMN2     COLUMN3
    ----- ----------- ----------- -----------
    Row 1          12          25          11
    Row 2          30           5          15
    
      2 record(s) selected.
```

and this,  you column-to-Rows .... simpler and without using unions or sysdummy1

```
db2 => WITH BASE(RID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) AS 
         (VALUES ('Row 1', 12, 25, 11), 
                 ('Row 2', 30, 5, 15)) 
--- in your case, you would start here, selecting directly from your real table 

      SELECT RID, P.COLUMN_NAME, P.COLUMN_VALUE  
      FROM BASE B, TABLE(VALUES 
                          ('Column1', B.COLUMN1 ), 
                          ('Column2', B.COLUMN2 ),  
                          ('Column3', B.COLUMN3 )) 
                   AS P(COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_VALUE)

RID   COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_VALUE
----- ----------- ------------
Row 1 Column1               12
Row 1 Column2               25
Row 1 Column3               11
Row 2 Column1               30
Row 2 Column2                5
Row 2 Column3               15

  6 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLcode 4772 reason 7 from the accelerator means "**The query uses multiple encoding schemes**."

Check this page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n4742.html . It advises:

> "If you need more information about why the statement cannot be
>   executed in the accelerator, issue the EXPLAIN statement and examine
>   the output of the table DSN_QUERYINFO_TABLE."

Additional information is on this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4LQ8_4.1.0/com.ibm.datatools.aqt.doc/gui/concepts/c_idaa_explain.html) which advises

> Ensure that all objects to which the query refers have the same
>   encoding scheme.

Talk with your DBA, discover the CCSID of the objects involved in your query, and rework the query accordingly, for example with temporary tables using the same encoding.

Comment: I would guess that sysibm.sysdummy1 is not the same CCSID as your user tables. Maybe create your own table with the values you need in it. E.g. `CREATE TABLE N(N INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY); INSERT INTO N VALUES 1; INSERT INTO N VALUES 2;` etc`

Comment: `select * from table(values(1)) union all select * from table(values(2)) union all select * from table(values(3))` would replace the sysibm.sysdummy1 references.